# Is there a way in sql to get month names from data

Tags: mysql

I am selecting a data range, which is working fine with my code and returning expected data. The problem is when i add code to retrieve by months i get null.

https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-date-functions/extract-month-from-date-sql/

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(date_time,1,10), SUM(Total), sum(Total_ly)) 
FROM Transaction 
WHERE Substring(date_time,1,10) between '01/03/2019' AND '04/04/2019' 
Group By date_time 
Having sum(Total)<>0;
```

So in my table is the following:

```
date_time \ Total 
01/03/2019  45.00    
02/03/2019  34.00
23/03/2019  12.00
01/04/2019  90.00
25/04/2019  32.00
```

Expected output:

```
March 2019  91.00
April 2019  122.00
```

All I am doing to the total column is summing it. 
Plus i know someone will ask why i am substring(date_time) for another application i need time but for this one i just need date.

Anyway what i was trying was using the MonthName function and passing the date but this will only work for one date not a range.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: [ALWAYS READ THE MANUAL FIRST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) ___Its a marvelous resource for developers___

Answer (score 0):

use `date_format()` function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTRING(date_time,1,10),"%M %Y"), SUM(Total), sum(Total_ly)) 
FROM Transaction 
WHERE Substring(date_time,1,10) between '01/03/2019' AND '04/04/2019' 
Group By DATE_FORMAT(SUBSTRING(date_time,1,10),"%M %Y") 
Having sum(Total)<>0
```

Comment: this also returns null, as its date_time is a string